# UNION working in phpmyadmin, but not in my PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, database, union

so the query below will run in my phpmyadmin (with the variables as actual values as course), but when I run it in my php code I only get the first field returned (as if the second query after the UNION was never run).

```
$result=mysql_query("(SELECT RID, Name, Address, City, State, Zip_Code, Phone 
                      FROM restaurant 
                      WHERE Name = '$sql_name' AND City = '$sql_location') 
                      UNION 
                      (SELECT RID, Name, Address, City, State, Zip_Code, Phone 
                      FROM restaurant 
                      WHERE Name = '$sql_name' OR City = 'sql_location') ");
```

Can anyone help me as to why this is?  Thanks for reading and I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is back again?

Comment: It's not producing an error of any kind...only the wrong output than what I want.

Comment: @Jocelyn: how do you know how exactly the data was processed before this query?

Comment: @zerkms: I don't know, hence the question mark at the end of my comment.

Comment: The first part is redundant. You may only leave the second subquery

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

```
City = 'sql_location')
        ^ missing '$' symbol
```

Comment: While this is a "correct" - the better answer would be to reduce the query only to the second part, since the second one **always** contains the first one

Answer (score 0):

Both of your union statements would return exactly the same records. UNion will filter out duplicates.

Comment: Nope. Only `UNION DISTINCT` will.

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski: `UNION` == `UNION DISTINCT` in mysql. Please read the link you gave ;-) Yeah, it's always weird when you try to RTFM someone but don't know for sure if you're correct

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski, In any event, I doubt he meant to have the same SQL statement for both parts of the union. And of course you were correct to point out the missing symbol.